# WCF is timing out while trying to reach http://w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous with netTcp Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-framework-version

I'm currently facing an issue where my WCF server is trying to reach http://w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, but times out every time it trys to send data to all clients. That is a bit of an issue as it generates additional load on my server and delays some telegrams. The server and the clients are located inside a priveate network with no communication to the internet, so it makes sense to me, that these calls time out.

But I cannot find the reason, why my server is trying to reach that endpoint at all. We never explicitly defined that address, though I have read, that WS-addressing has this exact endpoint as one of its defaults. But everything I find is related to HTTP-binding in some way and I cannot apply that as I am using NET-TCP bindings for my telegrams.

Even worse is, that this phenomenon manifests itself on my customers site, but we cannot reproduce this behavior in any of our test systems (which should have the same configuration as the system of the customer). I'm having a super hard time analyzing this issue, as I have inherited this software and am not super keen with WCF. Any suggestions, what I can change or check?

Comment: You can configure Timeout Values on a Binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding

Comment: Yes, I have done that and set it to one second. but that behavior is still not good enough. Isn't there a way to disable calls to that address?

Comment: Do you mean to prohibit the WCF service from accessing http://w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous?

Comment: yes, I want my service to not even try to access that url

Comment: I think this should be a problem with your WCF service. Under normal circumstances, the WCF service does not access this address. You can refer to the WCF service in the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/default-nettcpbinding

Comment: Yes, under normal circumstances, it shouldn't. And it doesn't do it in our development/testing enviromnet. But it does try to access that address at the customers site. Also, we create the binding in code and there are no files that configure the binding outside of our code base...

Comment: Same issue for me too! @Chrisi: did you find a solution?

Comment: We assumed it was due to high load in the network, but we haven't found a concrete solution yet